# Splitting std::wstring by "," symbol

Tags: parsing, c++11, wstring

All those questions contains answers and code which parses and splits std::string and not std::wstring.

When I'm trying to attempt such conversion I got following:

```
std::wstring sql;
std::wistringstream str( sql );
std::wstring s;
while( std::getline( str, s, ',' ) )
{
}

error C2780: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided
1>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\string(479) : see declaration of 'std::getline'
error C2784: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from 'std::wistringstream'
1>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\string(468) : see declaration of 'std::getline'
error C2782: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem)' : template parameter '_Elem' is ambiguous
1>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\string(468) : see declaration of 'std::getline'
1>          could be 'char'
1>          or       'wchar_t'
error C2780: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : expects 2 arguments - 3 provided
1>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\string(448) : see declaration of 'std::getline'
error C2784: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&' from 'std::wistringstream'
1>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\string(395) : see declaration of 'std::getline'
error C2782: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem)' : template parameter '_Elem' is ambiguous
1>          c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\string(395) : see declaration of 'std::getline'
1>          could be 'char'
1>          or       'wchar_t'
fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
```

This is with MSVC 2010.

As I said in the beginning - THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE. This question is explicitly about std::wstring and not std::string.

What am I doing wrong?

TIA!!

Comment: When using wide strings you should stick to them. Try `std::getline(str, s, L',');`. Also use better tools.

Comment: Using a narrow character literal. With wstring, use `L','`.

Comment: See [the documentation for character literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) for details. Although the documentation loses a lot of its value because your compiler doesn't support most of it.

Comment: @nwp, thx. I guess I just forgot to add 'L'.